# WCF with existing web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have webforms application which consists of a 3 layered proccess: Model, DAL, Presentation based on WebForms.

Now I have to update my project so that it calls a wcf service for getting data from database. I've been reading a lot on wcf but I don't understand the part with the classes with DataContract and DataMembers, because I have defined classes in my model layer. I use that classes to create database with entityframework. So do I need to define that classes in wcf again? And do I use dal layer to connect to the database?

I'm really new at this, so forgive me if the question is not good.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create DataMembers in the WCF seperately, what you have to do is, your application will call business layer, and business layer will call WCF service, and using WCF serivce call Data Tier Layer and do database operations, this is the way to follow it.

what you can do is add another separate layer for WCF service give DAL reference to it, at the same time also give DAL reference to BAL. And DON'T give WCF project reference to any one because you want it to be RESTFULL (i.e. to be access only through HTTP, ftp like protocols)

Here Iservice.cs is just interface which exposes methods to the outer world, it depicts what data, in what form and where it will be find. just implement that interface to any repository class in WCF project, which further will get data from DAL for you. Buisness Layer is the Only layer who will talk to Service layer.

Adding DAL reference to BAL is only for the metadata of the entities.